# Change font shape to OMS/cmsy/m/n to prevent warning

Tags: fonts

I would like to remove a warning that I receive when compiling this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
ab\textcopyright{}de % issues warning

ab\textcircled{c}de % same warning

ab\textrm{\textcopyright}de % looks ugly

%ab\textsym{\textcopyright}de % does not compile
\end{document}
```

The warning is

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmss/m/n' undefined
(Font) using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead on input line 4.
```

I am OK with latex doing this substitution, but if possible, I would like to get rid of the warning by proactively changing the font for the `\textcopyright` symbol. I know commands such as `\textrm`, but I haven't found the one which changes from "ss" to "sy". I also know about the `silence` package, but I want to do it "right".

Bonus question: I would like to use the lmodern package, then the warning is:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/lmss/m/n' undefined
(Font) using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead on input line 5.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\sffamily\Huge
ab\textcopyright{}de\par
ab\textcircled{c}de \par
ab\textrm{\textcopyright}de\par
\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont%% Helvetica
ab\textcopyright{}de\par
ab\textcircled{c}de \par
ab\textrm{\textcopyright}de

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `textcomp`, the symbols look very ugly (with lmodern) or even pixelated (without lmodern) :(

Comment: @bers They shouldn't look pixelated if you are using `fontenc`, even without `lmodern`, provided you have the type1 versions of Computer Modern installed. (cm-super usually.) If you load `textcomp`, you get a 'proper' copyright symbol rather than one faked on-the-fly. (When you use `\textcopyright`. When you create it yourself, you obviously get the symbol you construct.) Whether the fonts provide a symbol you find ugly is another issue. An alternative would be to use another font for that symbol.

Comment: If I don't use `lmodern`, I don't see any difference with `\textcircled{c}` between that case and one where I do not load `textcomp`. The difference with `\textcopyright` is that I get the pre-composed glyph if I load `textcomp`, I think.

Comment: Alright, so installing `cm-super` fixed the pixelation. Now, with `texcomp` and sans-serif fonts (either `lmodern` or `cmodern`), nothing looks any nice (neither textcopyright nor textcircled) except for `\textcircled{c}` in cmodern (which is not impacted by `textcomp`, I agree. But this doesn't give the gylph, I agree, too, which is the smaller pain visually. So I am close to using `\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont\textcircled{c}`, which does not use `textmodern`, so i can just as well discard `textmodern` and use `\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont\textcopyright`

Comment: Thanks for the visualization. Look how unacceptable the lmodern ones are :) The Helvetica one is nice, though. I accept this answer, since the original one (how to switch to cmsy) is not applicable if one wants glyphs.